# Css animation while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I have several div's and I want to add animation.  I use animate.css ( https://github.com/daneden/animate.css ) for it

```
<div class="first animated bounce">
...
</div>
<div class="second animated bounce">
...
</div>
```

And now animation starts after page is loaded, but I want to start animation when I scroll to div.

how can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: .scrollTop() in Jquery will allow you create that animation for you

Comment: Please update the post with the HTML and CSS code to debug easily

Comment: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

Comment: http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WOW.js, this library checks when the the element is visible and applies the animate.css animation that you have set in the elements class:

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

The docs for intalling it and configuring are pretty straightforward.